# Why linker can not resolve symbol?

Tags: c++, cmake, linker

Can not figure out what's the problem..
I have a CLion project using Cmake.

There I have two main targets

1. tstreamer - is a shared library, witch depends on libtorrent and wraps it

```
add_library(tstreamer SHARED tstreamer.cpp)
target_link_libraries(tstreamer PRIVATE torrent PUBLIC pthread)
```

2. test - is a CLI binary which uses tstreamer(1) library under the hood and DOES NOT NEED to use libtorrent directly

```
add_executable(test main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test tstreamer)
```

When I try to build this project I got linker error

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/test.dir/main.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN10libtorrent7sessionD1Ev'
//usr/local/lib/libtorrent.so.1.2.9: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Demangled symbol is libtorrent::session::~session()

My question is why I can not leave **PRIVATE torrent** in my shared library? Why I need to specify
libtorrent dependency twice - one for my shared lib and another for test binary?

Command to compile test binary is

```
/usr/bin/c++  -g   CMakeFiles/test.dir/main.cpp.o  -o test  -Wl,-rpath,/home/****/CLionProjects/t_streamer_lib/cmake-build-debug libtstreamer.so -lpthread
```

Why linker can not figure out that libtorrent is needed, after all ldd for tstreamer says it.

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc58513000)
    libtorrent.so.1.2.9 => /usr/local/lib/libtorrent.so.1.2.9 (0x00007f3b6cf56000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f3b6cd37000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f3b6c9ae000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f3b6c796000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f3b6c3a5000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f3b6dd12000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f3b6c007000)
```

**UPDATE**

Ok After I made this changes it compiles

```
add_library(tstreamer SHARED tstreamer.cpp)
target_link_libraries(tstreamer PRIVATE torrent PUBLIC pthread)

add_executable(test main.cpp **tstreamer.h**)
target_link_libraries(test tstreamer)
```

Comment: Without knowing anything specifically about `tstreamer`, if that library's header files define templates or inline header functions that call out to `libtorrent`, when you compile ***your*** code that uses those templates or inline header functions, that code becomes a part of ***your*** code too, and ***you*** must link to `libtorrent`. `tstreamer`'s wrapping is incomplete. Been there, done that, won the prize myself: I must link with `-lpthread` if my code uses `std::thread`, even though there's nothing in my code that uses the C library's posix thread stuff.

Comment: tstreamer uses libtorrent wich indeed uses boost

Comment: See update. It works after I added tstreamer.h to test target

Comment: This seems to be a C++, not C, question.

Comment: Addition of a header file into `add_executable` is just a hint for CMake that your executable needs that header and, if the header is not existed(or is not up-to-date), it should be generated before compiling the executable. The header is passed neither to the compiler nor linker, so their command lines won't be changed (you may check that).

Comment: With 2k reputation you should be aware that a solution should be placed in the **answer post**, not in the *question post*. And the question should be understandable even without solution.

Comment: did you try to make torrent `PUBLIC` in tstreamer ?

Comment: If I make torrent public it works. The question is why it should.be public, if test target does not need it directly